# SAS Question: option locale value different than server version. Why?

Tags: sas, locale

SAS EG 8.1 client with 9.4 server. When I look in EG's Help --> About and Click Configuration Details, at the very bottom in the Metadata Server section I can see that the value of Regional Parameters is "fr_CA" for French language, Canada.

However in my session if I run

```
proc options option=locale value;
```

the value is FR_FR (French language, France):

```
Informations sur la valeur de l'option SAS LOCALE
    Valeur :FR_FR
    Etendue : IOM ROOT COMP ENV
    Comment la valeur d'option est définie : Executive Startup
```

I'm guessing this value is different because it refers to my local/client EG installation? Also, what is "Executive Startup"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume it means it was set when the SAS session was created.

Here is what I get from PC-SAS.

```
13    proc options option=locale value;
14    run;

    SAS (r) Proprietary Software Release 9.4  TS1M5

Option Value Information For SAS Option LOCALE
    Value: EN_US
    Scope: SAS Session
    How option value set: Config File
    Config file name:
            C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\nls\u8\sasv9.cfg
```